# Recursion with Logo: Counting up and down

Tags: recursion, turtle-graphics

I am a newbie in the Logo programming language (the turtle's language). I am trying to implement a simple recursion program. I want to write a procedure (or several ones) that will get a natural number as input, type all the numbers from this number down to 1, and then back up to the original number.

I did manage to write a program that will print all the numbers down to 1, but I can't figure out how to go up again. I would like to ask for your assistance. Even those of you who are not familiar with Logo syntax will probably figure it out...

My code so far is:

```
to down :n
if :n = 0 [stop]
pr :n
make "n (:n - 1)
down (:n)
end
```

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> type all the numbers from this number down to 1, and then back up to
>   the original number.

This slight change to your program should do the trick:

```
to down :n
  if :n = 0 [stop]
  pr :n
  down :n - 1
  pr :n
end

down 10
```